# Ingragistic XamGrid: New record is not editable

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Given,

```
    <igDP:XamDataGrid Name="dataGrid" 
                          DataSource="{Binding RecordList}">
            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings >
                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AllowAddNew="true" AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed"/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
```

On running, I can see a empty new row on top of the grid. But none of the columns in the new row are editable !!! The columns are editable when I mark each of the Fields as editable.

Is it possible to have the add record functionality work while "without" explicitly marking each of the fields as editable ?

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best bet would be asking this on the infragistics netadvantage forum, but having said that...

As I understand what you want is a readonly datagrid (non-editable on its cells) to have a editable row to add new item...

1. Add a `CellValuePresenter` targetted `Style` under `XamDatagrid.Resources`.
2. This will check if the given cell value presenter is focused and represents the add new row.
3. If so it will make the parent field editable via some attached behavior.

   ```
   <igDP:XamDataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                     DataSource="{Binding}"
                     AutoFit="True">
       <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <MultiDataTrigger>                           
                       <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFocused,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Value="True"/>
                           <Condition Binding="{Binding Record.IsAddRecord,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                      Value="True"/>
                       </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                       <Setter 
                           Property="local:CellValuePresenterBehavior.AllowFieldEdit"
                           Value="True"/>
                   </MultiDataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
       <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
           <igDP:FieldLayout>
               <!-- Only show the first 4 fields to keep the display simple -->
               <igDP:Field Name="Key" Visibility="Visible">                        
                   <igDP:Field.Settings>
                       <igDP:FieldSettings
                                EditAsType="{x:Type System:String}"
                           EditorType="{x:Type Editors:XamTextEditor}" 
                                AllowEdit="False"/>
                   </igDP:Field.Settings>
               </igDP:Field>
               <igDP:Field Name="Value" Visibility="Visible">
                   <igDP:Field.Settings>
                       <igDP:FieldSettings
                                EditAsType="{x:Type System:String}"
                           EditorType="{x:Type Editors:XamTextEditor}" 
                                AllowEdit="False"/>
                   </igDP:Field.Settings>
               </igDP:Field>
           </igDP:FieldLayout>
       </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
       <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
           <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"
                                     AllowAddNew="True"
                                     AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed"
                                     HighlightAlternateRecords="True"/>
       </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
   </igDP:XamDataGrid>
   ```

And the attached behavior is as below...

```
public class CellValuePresenterBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty AllowFieldEditProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AllowFieldEdit",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CellValuePresenterBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnAllowFieldEditChanged));

    private static void OnAllowFieldEditChanged(
        DependencyObject depObj,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var cvp = depObj as CellValuePresenter;
        if (cvp != null)
        {
            cvp.Field.Settings.AllowEdit = (bool)args.NewValue;
        }
    }

    public static bool GetAllowFieldEdit(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return (bool) depObj.GetValue(AllowFieldEditProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAllowFieldEdit(DependencyObject depObj, bool value)
    {
        depObj.SetValue(AllowFieldEditProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.